# Is there a Photoshop plugin with additional transform resampling filters?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize, plugin

I'm from a VFX background (working with compositors) and I'm fairly new to Photoshop. I notice when performing transforms that there are only a few resampling options available (Nearest Neighbor, Bilinear and some Bicubic variants). Is there a plugin available to provide additional filters (e.g. Lanczos, Sinc)?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such hook in the API. Adobe just isn't a very big on signal processing*. You could of course make your own plugin but that wouldn't tie to the GUI very well

Dont look at Photoshop like a comp app. If you do then you'll be unhappy

* Adobe also does not do color correct processing of all the functions, by default. And even when they do they dont do so everywhere.

Comment: I'd like to use Photoshop to bring lots of elements together without losing quality. I notice that you can use a smart object to merge transforms and avoid a gradual degradation but the sampling options don't provide great quality and sometimes I need multiple transforms (to combine previously combined elements). Is Photoshop the wrong tool for this or am I missing something?

Comment: @WB Probably you should be using illustrator or indesign. But that depends on what your purpose is. But losing quality is a bit loaded most people lose quality and time because they can not define what quality they are after,

Comment: Naively, I'm just combining images for a brochure. There are a bunch of images at different sizes but I'd like to group some of the images into element of the final brochure, hence the multiple transforms. You're right that the transforms are bound to lose quality, I'm just trying to control it. I don't appear to get great quality, even with images that are larger than the final element size. I can sharpen after but it doesn't give me the quality I'd expect. Looks like it's just down to filtering. Are image transformations better in Indesign/Illustrator?

Comment: @WB thats why you DO NOT want to use Photoshop. Wherever scaling Photoshop does is ruined by the printer driver. Hence you send all images at the size you have. Which is not possible in Photoshop. Note your images need to be very big like 4K images for a A4 coverage

Comment: Right. That makes a lot of sense. So if I assemble the images in Indesign then it won't apply the transforms until the final layout goes to the printer. Sounds like I need a graphic design software 101. (Suggestions welcome but it's probably one for me to look into.)